# How to get the namespace of a var in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, namespaces

I am currently using the following which *works* - but it seems a bit of a cludge

```
(defn get-namespace
  [qualified-var]
  {:pre [(var? qualified-var)]}
  (the-ns
   (symbol
    (apply str (drop 2 (first (str/split (str qualified-var) #"/")))))))
```

ignoring the ugly string splitting (quick and dirty) is there a built in to do this?

Comment: Try `(-> qualified-var meta :ns)`

Comment: do you want to write this as an aswer :D or should I just delete the question?

Comment: Seems useful q&a, either get @ez121sl to answer and accept or answer yourself and accept

Comment: The question is fine. I'll write up the answer later or maybe someone else will do it in the mean time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The var's metadata contains a reference to its namespace under the `:ns` key. That would be the namespace in which the var is defined. The var's metadata can be accessed using the `meta` function. Putting it all together, we get `(-> some-var meta :ns)` and we can experiment a bit:

```
(def x "foo")
;; #'user/x
(-> #'x meta :ns)
;; #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x396bcdb0 "user"]
(-> #'clojure.core/map meta :ns)
;; #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x28412381 "clojure.core"]
```

A full example may look like this:

```
(defn var-namespace
  [qualified-var]
  {:pre [(var? qualified-var)]}
  (-> qualified-var meta :ns))
```